# How to convert an output from a curl into a string object

Tags: python, curl, output

I'm doing a curl request that returns something like this :

```
b'{\n  "output": {\n    id": "11-222-33-44-5abcd6efg"\n  }\n}\n'
```

then I'm doing

```
id=re.sub("\{.*\: \"", "", output)
id=re.sub("\" *\}.*", "", id)
```

but i get : TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

I'd like to convert the output into string maybe it would work then, or if you have any other idea, my goal is to get that id. Doing this in Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, you should try

```
# utf-8 is used here because it is a very common encoding, but you
# need to use the encoding your data is actually in.

output = output.decode('utf-8')
```

[Similar problem solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-string)

Answer (score 2):

If `g` is your binary string, `g.decode("utf-8")` will give you what you have asked.